# EF Core 2.2, Passing String Parameter to FromSql Statement

Tags: entity-framework-core

```
public List<JC_PHASE_MASTER_TOTAL1_MC> GetAllByCompanyCodeJobNumber()
{
    return _context.JC_PHASE_MASTER_TOTAL1_MC.FromSql(
        $"SELECT * FROM JC_PHASE_MASTER_TOTAL1_MC WHERE (Job_Number = '  123')"
    ).ToList();
}

Corresponding SQL:

SELECT *
FROM JC_PHASE_MASTER_TOTAL1_MC
WHERE
    (Job_Number = '  123')
```

The Job_Number field in the table is a varchar and is stored with leading spaces for any unused digits.  When I run the above function with Job_Number hard-coded, the query runs as intended.  However, the SQL produced by passing the same value as a parameter looks like this and the SQL run appears to pass a number rather than a string:

```
public List<JC_PHASE_MASTER_TOTAL1_MC> GetAllByCompanyCodeJobNumber(string jobNumber)
{
    return _context.JC_PHASE_MASTER_TOTAL1_MC.FromSql(
        $"SELECT * FROM JC_PHASE_MASTER_TOTAL1_MC WHERE (Job_Number = {jobNumber})"
    ).ToList();
}

Corresponding SQL with '   123' passed to the jobNumber string parameter:

SELECT *
FROM JC_PHASE_MASTER_TOTAL1_MC
WHERE
    (Job_Number = 123)
```

Why is the string parameter passed into the SQL statement as 123 and not '   123'?  I'm unsure how to adjust my function so that the parameter is not passed as a number.

Revised code per accepted solution:

```
public List<JC_PHASE_MASTER_TOTAL1_MC>GetAllByCompanyCodeJobNumber(string jobNumber)
{
    var jobNumberParameter = new SqlParameter("@jobNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    jobNumberParameter.Value = jobNumber;

    return _context.JC_PHASE_MASTER_TOTAL1_MC.FromSql(
        $"SELECT * FROM JC_PHASE_MASTER_TOTAL1_MC WHERE (Job_Number = {jobNumberParameter})"
    ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I've adjusted my initial post to isolate my question.  It's less of a question about performance and more of a realization that the parameter I created is not being passed as I intended.

Comment: EF Core 2.2 (as the title states), SQL Server, the table field is varchar (as stated in the question).  I will consider refactoring and cleaning up the code once the query works.  Until then I would rather figure out the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly setting the SQL data type, something like:

```
public List<JC_PHASE_MASTER_TOTAL1_MC>GetAllByCompanyCodeJobNumber(string jobNumber)
{
    var jobNumberParameter = new SqlParameter("@jobNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    jobNumberParameter.Value = jobNumber;

    return _context.JC_PHASE_MASTER_TOTAL1_MC.FromSql(
        $"SELECT * FROM JC_PHASE_MASTER_TOTAL1_MC WHERE (Job_Number = {jobNumberParameter})"
    ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this lead me down the path to fix my issue.  I've updated my post with the code I ended up using.

Comment: I didn't have a machine to test on at the time, glad it got you close enough, I've aligned my answer with your updated question