# Entity Framework: Passing String Parameter to FromSql Statement in Version 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I am trying to pass a string parameter to a SQL Query ,
Receiving error below. How can I resolve this? Currently utilizing answer [EF Core 2.2, Passing String Parameter to FromSql Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171592/ef-core-2-2-passing-string-parameter-to-fromsql-statement)

> Input String was not in a correct format.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetProduct(string productKey)
{
    var productParameter = new SqlParameter("@productKey", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    productParameter.Value = productKey;

    var productIdList = db.TestDb
        .FromSql($"select ProductId from dbo.Product product" +
            "   (where product.ProductKey = {productParameter})" )
            .Select(c => c.ProductId).ToList();
```

It is type varchar(6) from ProductKey

Using Net Core 2.2

Comment: You need to identify what columns to select., and use the keyword FROM before the table name.  SELECT something FROM table WHERE stuff

Comment: Do you mean to assign productKey as the parameter value?  you have productNumber, and I don't see where that's defined.

Comment: What is the data type of ProductKey in your database?

Comment: The accepted answer to the question you linked to is wrong, so your code is wrong too.

Comment: Side note:  You don't need the `.Select(c => c.ProductId)` since you specify the column name in the query and it's the only column you're returning.  Perhaps '.ToList()' ?

Comment: Is it not the way how parameter is passed in query? Should this not be with '@' as prefix?

Comment: hi devlin, fixed some parts, feel free to remove comments above, thanks for helping me clarify questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `FromSql` you should construct your code like this to properly apply the SqlParameter:

```
var productIdList = db.TestDb
    .FromSql($"select ProductId from dbo.Product product where product.ProductKey = @productKey",productParameter )
    .Select(c => c.ProductId).ToList();
```

Depending on the version of EF you are using, you could also use [`FromSqlInterpolated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlinterpolated?view=efcore-3.1) instead of `FromSql` and do away with the SqlParameter altoghter.

Answer (score 1):

1) Query is not correct: you don't have FROM statement, which is required.
I presume that you wanted something like

```
select productKey 
from dbo.Product product 
where product.Product = <paramName>
```

2) When using FromSQL: in the query string you have to input the name of the parameter, not the instance. So change *{productParameter}* to *@productKey*

3) Pass the SqlParameter instance as second argument to FromSql method.

```
var productParameter = new SqlParameter("@productKey", SqlDbType.VarChar);
productParameter.Value = productNumber;     

var product= db.Tra
    .FromSql($@"
        select productKey 
        from dbo.Product product 
        where product.ProductKey = {productParameter.Name}", productParameter);
```

Comment: Your code does not match your explanation. You are not using `@productKey` in the sql.

Comment: You can use **@productKey** instead of {productParameter.Name}.
In fact productParameter.Name is @productKey. You can check it during debug session. I just used here productParameter.Name to avoid duplication in the code.

Comment: I know you can use it but what is the point of the sql parameter if you are just going to use interpolation to build sql?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly:
1) SqlParameter prevents SQL injections
2) SqlParameter prevents SQL Server to build execution plans again and again when you make a query with different product id in where clause.

Comment: You didn't understand. I'm not arguing that you shouldn't use parameters. I'm saying your code is not technically using one. By using `{productParameter.Name}` you are using string interpolation, you are not using the SqlParameter that is passed to the Command. It should be: `where product.ProductKey = @productKey"`. And you can drop the `$` on the string.

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick:

```
var productParameter = new SqlParameter("@productKey", productKey);

var productIdList = db.TestDb
    .FromSql("select ProductId from dbo.Product where ProductKey = @productParameter",productParameter )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You forgot to add the parameter to the command. Just putting "@productKey" in the string won't work.